# Want to print uitableview to pdf

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-generation

Not able to preview pdf files.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let pdfURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/sample1.pdf"))
            let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: pdfURL)
            interactionController.delegate = self
            interactionController.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
        })
```

it opens pdf but no preview is available , and its working perfect on Simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the file is stored online and you have a url to the file what you can do is use the google docs to display the file use this link

http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=URL_TO_THE_FILE

and use a WebView to display it.

Hope the answer helps.